Incorrect Jest Module Name Mapper: Could not locate module
I am using Jest v29.7.0 as well as babel-jest v29.7.0.
This is my jest.config.js file
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    rootDir: './',
    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/public/js'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/public/js/components/$1',
    },
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.jsx'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/output/coverage',
    coverageReporters: ['html', 'text-summary'],
    testTimeout: 10000,
    roots: ['./public/js/components', './test/spec'],
    collectCoverageFrom: ['./public/js/**/*.{js,jsx}']
};


When trying to run one particular test: npm run test-jest -- test/spec/components/UserProfile/Account/Payments.spec.js 
Error from Jest
Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module components/UserProfile/Account/Payments mapped as:
    /Users/XXXXXXX/repo/public/js/components/$1.
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^components\/(.*)$/": "/Users/XXXXXXX/repo/public/js/components/$1"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      2 | import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
      3 | import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
    > 4 | import Payments from 'components/UserProfile/Account/Payments';
        | ^
      5 |
      6 | // Mock implementations
      7 | const mockGetState = jest.fn();

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.require (test/spec/components/UserProfile/Account/Payments.spec.js:4:1)
          at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)


In my project I don't use extensions when importing, for example I use import Payments from 'components/UserProfile/Account/Payments'; without having to use .jsx and my Webpack config understands this.
But I am new to Jest and don't know how to get it to understand the imports without extensions when using them in tests.
My Simple failing test
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import Payments from 'components/UserProfile/Account/Payments';

describe('Payments Component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        render(<Payments />);
    });
});

babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
};


jest.setup.js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

What am I missing?

Shot in the dark: the moduleDirectories is suspicious to me. What happens if you simply do not define moduleDirectories or you just have only node_modules in it?

The other thing to check is that the file and directory names UserProfile, Account and Payments.jsx do indeed have that exact case (e.g. its Payments.jsx not payments.jsx) on the file system. Imports are case sensitive in node. Webpack hides this.

The issue was actually adding custom extensions to the moduleFileExtensions array. I have files that are named .custom.jsx for example and so I had to add custom.jsx to that array and then started running properly!
